# FTP RETR Command throws "No route to host"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

So I am working with ftplib in python 2.7 to connect to a remote FTP server (from another server) in order to download a file. When I execute the RETR command, it throws:

```
        self.get_connection().retrbinary("RETR " + source, open(destination, 'wb').write)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 414, in retrbinary
        conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
        return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 335, in ntransfercmd
        conn = socket.create_connection((host, port), self.timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
        raise err
    socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Now my code is working fine in another server, but in this one it seems not. So I tried `ping x.x.x.x` (it works), I use `telnet x.x.x.x 21` (it works), `ftp x.x.x.x` (it works!). Then I went to the firewall (on both servers) and allowed all in & out traffic and still getting the same error...

Any ideas ?! (As I said this is working fine on a third server... and it seems that the login command works fine but not the RETR)

**Edit:**

This is a sample of commands executed directly in ftp

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... to connect to a remote FTP server

According to your description you connect to a remote server but the server shows that it uses private IP addresses. My guess is that the address the server is aware of (10.0.0.8) is not the address you use to connect to the server, i.e. that the server is behind some router and there is port forwarding or address translation done.

Unfortunately FTP does not really work when one of the parties is behind a router. You might play around with passive and active mode when client is behind router (passive) or server (active). But if both are behind a router you  have usually lost.

Comment: Thank you Steffen for your answer, unfortunately you are right... since what I wanted to do is just a one time matter, I did it the hard way...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to a FTPES server?

Try this:

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
creds = [
    'host', 'username',
    'password']
ftps = FTP_TLS(*creds)
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
```

This should list the files present in the directory

you can than use something like,

```
ftps.retrbinary("RETR " + 'test.csv' ,open('test.csv', 'wb').write)
```

to retrieve the file from the server and writing it locally.

[FTPLIB](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html)